# PostgreSQL не видит прав доступа

Tags: sql, postgresql

Мною были розданы права доступа на функции в БД, однако они непонятным для меня образом игнорируются. В каждой функции я указываю `SECURITY DEFINER`, чтобы ее мог взывать каждый у кого есть на нее права.

Таким образом я даю права на функции, но эту функцию по непонятным мне причинам может вызывать и другим пользователь у которого нету прав на нее. Подскажите с решение этой проблемы.

```
GRANT execute ON function create_order(integer,varchar) to c_role;
```

Права доступа, которые выдаю на представления полностью работают, а с функциями такая проблема.

Comment: `SECURITY DEFINER` никак не связано с доступом к функции. Оно определяет, что при выполнении функции будут использоваться права доступа создателя функции, а не её исполнителя, к объектам БД. Т.е. через функцию ограниченный юзер может получить доступ к данным, к которым у него прямого доступа нет.

Comment: @Akina Да, я Вас понимаю. Вот допустим я не давал `Grant` на другого юзера, однако он почему-то может вызывать эту функцию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> может вызывать и другим пользователь у которого нету прав на нее

А вы сами **отобрали** права запуска? Строго [по документации:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)

> Another point to keep in mind is that by default, execute privilege is
> granted to PUBLIC for newly created functions (see Section 5.7 for
> more information). Frequently you will wish to restrict use of a
> security definer function to only some users. To do that, you must
> revoke the default PUBLIC privileges and then grant execute privilege
> selectively. To avoid having a window where the new function is
> accessible to all, create it and set the privileges within a single
> transaction. For example:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE FUNCTION check_password(uname TEXT, pass TEXT) ... SECURITY DEFINER;
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION check_password(uname TEXT, pass TEXT) FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION check_password(uname TEXT, pass TEXT) TO admins;
COMMIT;
```

По-умолчанию `create function` предоставляет право `execute` для всех.

Comment: Блин, я забыл это. Благодарю за помощь в решении данной задачи.

Comment: Да, конечно. Спасибо еще раз